# Adding extra variables to new host php form

Tags: php, forms

im just trying to set up a new email form on my website and i have managed to get it working to grab the email, the comments and the name from the form and send them to my designated email address when the user presses submit - My question is how do i add extra feilds lets say vehicle registration and phone number ?

i assumed i would add 2 more fields to the form using same attributes but with different id`s and then edit the send-mail.php file and add those 2 new variables next to the ones already in the send-mail.php file  ie the email variable and name variable and comment variable.

this is the code i have come up with, as it is now it still works but i dont get all fo the information sent to my email its missing the 2 new variables ....

```
  <!-- form -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form-validation.js"></script>
                <form id="contactForm" action="#" method="post">
                    <h2 class="heading">Contact us using this form</h2>
                    <p>If you have any queries at all or just want to get rid of your car as soon as possible then just leave us the requested details on the form below, press send and a member of our team will get back to you soon.</p>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div>
                            <input name="name"  id="name" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your full name" />
                            <label>Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input name="email"  id="email" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your email address" />
                            <label>Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                            <input name="reg"  id="reg" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your vehicle registration" />
                            <label>Vehicle Registration</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                            <input name="phone"  id="phone" type="text" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your phone number" />
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea  name="comments"  id="comments" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-poshytip" title="Enter your comments"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <!-- send mail configuration -->
                        <input type="hidden" value="enquiries@scrapyourmotor.com" name="to" id="to" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="ScrapYourMotor FORM" name="subject" id="subject" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="send-mail.php" name="sendMailUrl" id="sendMailUrl" />
                        <!-- ENDS send mail configuration -->

                        <p><input type="button" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" /> <span id="error" class="warning">Message</span></p>
                    </fieldset>

                </form>
                <p id="sent-form-msg" class="success">Form data sent. Thanks for your comments.</p>
                <!-- ENDS form -->
```

and the php file ....

```
                <?php
                //vars
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $to = explode(',', $_POST['to'] );

                $from = $_POST['email'];

                //data
                $msg = "NAME: "  .$_POST['name']    ."<br>\n";
                $msg .= "EMAIL: "  .$_POST['email']    ."<br>\n";
                $msg .= "REG: "  .$_POST['reg']    ."<br>\n";
                $msg .= "PHONE: "  .$_POST['phone']    ."<br>\n";
                $msg .= "COMMENTS: "  .$_POST['comments']    ."<br>\n";

                //Headers
                $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
                $headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;


                //send for each mail
                foreach($to as $mail){
                   mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);
                }

                ?>
```

where am i going wrong? this is the output i get in my email:

NAME: the name i sent

EMAIL: the email i sent

VEHICLE REGISTRATION: (nothing here?)

PHONE NUMBER: (nothing here?)

COMMENTS: the comments i sent

thanks for any help people  :)

Comment: Im used to linux servers, i have working forms set up fine for linux/php with any variables i choose to use however this server must be windows and its only accepting email and name obviously im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ah well silly me i forgot to also update the form-validation.js file with the 2 new variables :) ...

```
        // reg
    var reg = $("input#reg").val();
    if(reg == ""){
        $("#error").fadeIn().text("Reg required");
        $("input#reg").focus();
        return false;
    }

    // comments
    var comments = $("#comments").val();

    // phone
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
```